# extract slice of objects from associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array like below :

```
$array = array(
  'id1' => 'value1',
  'id2' => 'value2',
  'id3' => 'value3',
  'id4' => 'value4',
  'id5' => 'value5',
);
```

And I want to extract a slice of objects from the array :
so say I want first two objects, the result will be :

```
$array = array(
  'id1' => 'value1',
  'id2' => 'value2',
);
```

And Note that I dont know the value of the IDs

`array_slice($array, 0, 2)` is not the desired result as the key will become 0 and 1 .

Is there a dymanic way without having to loop through them all ?

Comment: Fourth parameter is `bool $preserve_keys = false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fourth parameter of [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) function is `bool $preserve_keys = false`.

So your call is:

```
array_slice($array, 0, 2, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

`array_slice()` takes another optional boolean argument as shown in the PHP's documentation.

> ```
> array array_slice ( array $array , int $offset [, int $length = NULL
> [, bool $preserve_keys = false ]] )
> ```
>
> preserve_keys
>
> Note that array_slice() will reorder and reset the numeric array indices by default. You can change this behaviour by setting
>   preserve_keys to TRUE.

So, this might be it.